# While loop going forever

Tags: javascript, algorithm, while-loop

I have a while that keeps running even if the condition is met which is `el.tagName !== 'H2'` 
I do not know why it's still running after it finds the closest Header which in this case is H2. You can view the codepn here https://codepen.io/theMugician/pen/wQjJjj

```
function grabClosestHeader (el) {

    var parent = el.parentNode;
    el = parent.firstChild;
    while (el.tagName !== 'H2') {

        el = el.nextSibling;
        console.log(el);
        if( el != null && el.tagName === 'H2') {
            console.log('This is the H2 Tag');
        }
        if (el === null) {
            console.log('This is NULL');

            parent = parent.parentNode;
            el = parent.firstChild;
        }

    }


    // Then return the matched element
    console.log(el.tagName);
    return el;
}
```

Comment: In your codepen, you are never calling `grabClosestHeader()`. You _are_ calling `closestHeader()` (which doesn't exist) though. Typo? Changing it to your function call to `grabClosestHeader()` does log all the elements until the `<html>` after which it crashes because it has no parents anymore. No sign of an infinite loop anywhere.